# Property validation failure "SNSDestination" while creating a ConfigurationSetEventDestination from CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, serverless-framework

I'm trying to create a `ConfigurationSetEventDestination` using [serverless resources](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/) but it not recognizing the `EventDestination` for value `SNSDestination`, here is the output.

[image]

And here the resource from `serverless.yml`

```
resources:
  Resources:
    HandleEmailsEvents:
      Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
      Properties:
        DisplayName: 'Handle emails events (${self:custom.stage})'
        TopicName: 'HandleEmailsEvents'
    ConfigurationSet:
      Type: 'AWS::SES::ConfigurationSet'
      Properties:
        Name: 'EMAIL_TRACKING'
    ConfigurationSetEventDestination:
      Type: 'AWS::SES::ConfigurationSetEventDestination'
      Properties:
        ConfigurationSetName: 'EMAIL_TRACKING'
        EventDestination:
          Name: 'EMAIL_TRACKING_DESTINATION'
          Enabled: true
          MatchingEventTypes:
            - bounce
            - complaint
          SNSDestination:
            TopicARN:
              Ref: 'HandleEmailsEvents'
```

Following the documentation [ConfigurationSetEventDestination EventDestination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ses-configurationseteventdestination-eventdestination.html) seems to not be available, but [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_EventDestination.html) it is with [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SNSDestination.html) description object.

SNSDestination is also available when creating from console

[image]

@AWS What's going on here?

Thanks,

*PS: I'm not the only one...*

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=858616&#858616

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=809004&#809004

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=848013&#848013

**[UPDATED]**

I tried creating the same via nodejs sdk, it works, its possible, docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#createConfigurationSetEventDestination-property).

**Could be something with serverless CloudFormation generated stack?**

```
let ses = new AWS.SES()
const destinationParams = {
  ConfigurationSetName: 'test',
  EventDestination: {
    Name: 'xxxxx2',
    MatchingEventTypes: ['send', 'reject', 'bounce', 'complaint', 'delivery', 'open', 'click'],
    Enabled: true,
    SNSDestination: {
      TopicARN: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxx:test',
    },
  },
};

ses.createConfigurationSetEventDestination(destinationParams, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

[image]

Comment: I am encountering the exact same issue right now. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: Nop, I end up creating manually and rendering using key name instead of all inside cloudformation stack

Comment: Oh man, too bad. Thaanks for the info!

Comment: AS per documentation as of now, SNS cannot be a destination in cloudformation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, if you are using `serverless` framework.

1- Create a Resource to create the `ConfigurationSet` in serverless.yml

```
resources:
  Resources:
    ConfigurationSet:
      Type: 'AWS::SES::ConfigurationSet'
      Properties:
        Name: 'EMAIL_TRACKING'
```

2- Install `serverless-ses-sns`

```
npm install --save-dev serverless-ses-sns
```

3- Add to serverless.yml

```
plugins:
  - serverless-ses-sns
```

4- Finally add the configuration in serverless.yml

```
custom:
  snsDestination:
    region: <region> # If absent, self:provider.region will be used
    configurationSet: 'EMAIL_TRACKING'
    topicArn: <topic arn> # If absent, one will be created
    events: # One or more of the following
      - renderingFailure
      - reject
      - bounce
      - send
      - complaint
      - delivery
      - open
      - click
```

*[Reference for the plugin](https://github.com/Advanon/serverless-ses-sns)*

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon the same issue, so as of now, SNS cannot be passed as an event destination using cloudformation. For more info refer to the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ses-configurationseteventdestination-eventdestination.html#cfn-ses-configurationseteventdestination-eventdestination-matchingeventtypes), Do checkout the **NOTE**, its explicitly mentioned there.